# Java android Listview on resume show selected item

Tags: java, android

Hi I don't know how I can show a selected (chosen) item on resume activity (when we return to activity) I always show a top op my list

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startService();
    btConfirmPGO.setEnabled(false);
    btNotePGO.setEnabled(false);
    btDetailsPGO.setEnabled(false);
    if (NotePGOActivity.idTypeNote != null) {
        update();
    }
    String[] selectionVals = {NewDataAdapter.objectId, NewDataAdapter.lineId};
    tasks.clear();
    if (!isSort && !isFiltr) {
        getAllTasks();
    } else if (isSort && !isFiltr) {
        getAllTasks1(sortColumn[0], sort[0]);
    } else if (!isSort && isFiltr) {
        getAllTasks2(column[0], sort[0], filtrText);
    } else if (isSort && isFiltr) {
        getAllTasks3(column[0], sort[0], filtrText, sortColumn[0]);
    }
    Page page = config.getItems().get(1).getPages().get(0);
    myAdapter = new NewLineDataAdapter(this, parseTrasyToDataRow(tasks), page);

    list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: the easiest way to do is you can use `list.setSelection(postion)`. you can use static variable to tract the position of the cell in your BaseActivity.class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont initialize adapter every time.

Just initialize on `onCreate()`

then modify using `setterData()` if any change occured only.

So there is no anomalies or unrecognized refresh occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
why initialize adapter on onResume.
call your adapter onCreate.

if update your value in listview  on onResume then store position and onResume set listView on taht position.
```

Answer (score 0):

store your position value in bundle and get those position onresume, it will helps you alot but you need to use saveInstance method for doing this operation